# Why does VS change the value of Checkbox to null when bound to Bit column

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCuwV.png)

I have a checkbox bound to a Bit field in SQL database. The field is defined as Active_Ind(Bit,not null). The control is Checkbox, AutoCheck=false, Checked=True, CheckedState=Checked. When the form is displayed the control is checked. When I click on the save Icon on the navigation bar. I stopped the code and the checkedState is checked. But when I get to the update code I get the error

> "Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Active_Ind', table 'LazerMaintenance.dbo.Operators'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

I have searched the web for days on this but have not found a straight forward answer that worked.

```
Private Sub OperatorsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OperatorsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

    Me.Validate()
    Me.OperatorsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    If IsNothing(ckbActive_Ind) Then 
                <-- here the checkbox is checked
    End If
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LazerMaintenanceDataSet)

End Sub
```

Binding source:
Me.ckbActive_Ind.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("CheckState", Me.OperatorsBindingSource, "Active_Ind", True, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "1"))

Somewhere between when I click on save and it attempts to save the field is nulled. Is it because of the datatype? What I need to happen is for the checkbox to default to active_Ind(True,1) when adding a new employee and save it to the database. 
It works as long as the user checks the box. Setting Checked to true in properties causes the Null value.

Comment: You could setup the default value for the column in SQL.  This would prevent the null error.

Comment: What does the binding look like for the field?

Comment: ckbActive_Ind is never Nothing if the control exists on the form.